# Flutter add button without margin

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to implement a button without margin.

My code is :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppState(
      child: new Scaffold(

          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF031e39),
            title: Text("MY APP"),
          ),
          body:

          ButtonTheme(
            buttonColor: Color(0xFF031e39),
            minWidth: double.infinity,
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Color(0xFF81A483),
              onPressed: () {
                launchSearch();
              },
              child: Text('Search',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result is :

[image]

I have tried all different ways but I cannot figure out a solution so the button has not margin.

If I put a widget on top of my button in a column I get the same results:

[image]

How can I have a FlatButton without any margin ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unwanted space appearing between RaisedButton widgets in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714646/unwanted-space-appearing-between-raisedbutton-widgets-in-a-column)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2994d3562a0abb4a4db0fefdab27907e934cd161/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L206). It looks like Flutter pads out buttons that are smaller than the target tap size (48 x 48), you can get around it by:

1. Make your button height larger than or equal to 48

or

2. Add `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,` to your `FlatButton`.

Comment: It saved me hours.

Comment: It still leaves a tiny padding.
Another workaround is to use RichText with TapGestureRecognizer() instead of FlatButton. It can be not convenient to tap, but it may be the only way to fit into your design.

Comment: +1 Now that FlatButton is deprecated, prevent the mystery margin by adding `tapTargetSize:   MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` to the `ButtonStyle` for your `TextButton`. <gripe>Hidden nonsense like this is not what I expect from an awesome platform like Flutter</gripe>

Answer (score 3):

I got it but making some modifications.
Instead of using a `ButtonTheme` and a `FlatButton` I used a `Container` and a `FloatingActionButton`

With `Container` you can set the size in the screen. With `FloatingActionButton` you can set the position of the button in the `Scaffold`, which in this case is in all the screen.
To make the button flat I putted the attribute `elevation` to 0.0, so the button looks like flat.

```
appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF031e39),
      title: Text("MY APP"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF81A483),
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        elevation: 0.0,
        onPressed: () {
          print("entra");
        },
        child: Text(
          'Search',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

use: 
 **materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,**

```
FlatButton(
    textColor: GFColors.WHITE,
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        child: Text(
            "BLOG",
            style: TextStyle( 
            fontSize: 12.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal 
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
    },
),
```